# Wordpress Multisite + Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have an issue regarding Woocommerce and Wordpress, I would like to use the same product library on all the sites that i create in my multi-site.  all the sites will have the same products. How can i solve this?

if i check the Woocommerce information site they say that this is not a standard feature and it would not work like this for multi-site. I have tried both with Woocommerce and MarketPress, none off them work is i want them to do in the multi-site feature.

Have anybody solve this issue ?

BR
Mtz

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible as far as I know. WordPress Multisite creates seperate databases per site you create. So all the products will be in their own database from the website it was created in.

I think you should consider building a custom mechanisme that fires from a cron-job and will copy all the products (and variations, images, meta) from a parent site to all the subsites.

But this won't be easy, and is not simple code answer for this.

Comment: Definitely agree. I know Skyverge was working on something a while back but I've not heard anything about it recently.This is a very complex question that the OP isn't going to get answered for free on SO.

Comment: Thx for your answer, This is also a solution but it demands alot of code to also work with adding and removing products.  Do you know if there is a certain "config" for the different sites?

The "multi-site" function just copy all the database table and adds a new prefix with _01_ .

Comment: Niels, i think i can manage the cronjob, what about the stock amount,  that's much much complex, any ideas?

Comment: On every order you should hook in to the action that is called by WooCommerce for stock decrease, and push the new result to your other shops.You should do the same for increase on order cancellation.